# Find top level key in multidimensional object by value of second level key in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I have and multidimensional object that looks like this:

```
obj = {
    'someString': {
        name: 'John',
        page: 'some url',
        number: 4
    },
    'someString2': {
        name: 'Bill',
        page: 'some url',
        number: 7
    }
}
```

How do I find the first level key (in this case "someString2") where "number" is equal to 7?

The number is always unique and is the only thing I know beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. Using `Array.find` function to look for the appropriate key.

```js
const numberToLookFor = 7;

const data = {
    someString: {
        name: 'John',
        page: 'some url',
        number: 4,
    },
    someString2: {
        name: 'Bill',
        page: 'some url',
        number: 7,
    },
};

const myKey = Object.keys(data).find(x => data[x].number === numberToLookFor);


console.log(myKey);
```